# SharedPreferences not working when app re-opens

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am saving a boolean value to my shared preferences but when i re-open my app it doens't work.

Here is the code

```
public  static boolean isSeen;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b);
        milestoneCheck();
}


public void milestoneCheck(){
    totalKm = (int) Float.parseFloat(TripsInfo.km.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1));


    Log.d("test", "before" + isSeen);

    if (totalKm == 84 && !isSeen) {
        updateTrue(true);
        Log.d("test", "inside" + isSeen);
        isSeen=readFromSharedPrefs();
    }

    Log.d("test", "after" + isSeen);

}

private void updateTrue(Boolean value) {

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("inactivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("inactive", value);
    editor.apply();
}

public boolean readFromSharedPrefs() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesIn = getSharedPreferences("inactivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return sharedPreferencesIn.getBoolean("inactive", false);
}
```

I want it to be true after i re-open my app and it's false again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187857/discussion-on-question-by-alex-kolydas-sharedpreferences-not-working-when-app-re).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isSeen` is always be false because you forget to assign last value from preference.

and when you go from an other activity to this it is still true becuase you declared it as static this mean the value remain as long as the app lives.

**Solution:**

add `isSeen=readFromSharedPrefs();` before if statment

```
public void milestoneCheck(){
totalKm = (int) Float.parseFloat(TripsInfo.km.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1));

  isSeen=readFromSharedPrefs();
  Log.d("test", "before" + isSeen);

 if (totalKm == 84 && !isSeen) {
    updateTrue(true);
    Log.d("test", "inside" + isSeen);
    isSeen=readFromSharedPrefs();
}

Log.d("test", "after" + isSeen);

}
```